# What does EntityMap::iterator.second perform?

Tags: c++, function, iterator, entity

Can some please explain what EntityMap::iterator with a .second does?

I've been looking all over but can't seem to find anything my thought is that it is iterating thru the EntityMap once a second but again I don't know.  This is using the KDIS library.

```
EntityMap::iterator entityIterator;
for (entityIterator = m_entities.begin(); entityIterator != m_entities.end(); ++entityIterator)
  {
    Entity_State_PDU& pdu = (*entityIterator).second;
    PrintEntityStatePDU(tArrival, pdu);
  }
```

Comment: Are you talking about this EntityMap from AMPL? I can't findan EntityMap in the standard C++ libraries.
http://ampl.com/api/1.2.2/cpp/classes/entitymap.html

Comment: It is from this library: https://sourceforge.net/p/kdis/wiki/Main_Page/

Answer (score 0):

Alright...I had to hunt down someone who really understands this stuff but I have an answer.  What I was specifically asking about wasn't about the stl::map::list it was specifically how the EntityMap was laid out in the KDIS library and what ".second" does with the EntityMap iterator.  So .second gets the information from the EntityMap * ID in this case we get the value of the EntityID of the EntityMap.  We create an iterator and "iterator.second" gets the value within the map at that specific EntityID.  Hopefully I explained that well enough.